Seeing IllegalArgumentException warning in logs: "Illegal initial capacity: -231741684"
I am seeing the below warning message in the system.logs. No impact seen in the cluster, want to understand what does the warning mean and how to mitigate the same.
Cassandra Version - Apache Cassandra 2.2.10
OS - RHEL 7
WARN  \[insights-3-1\] 2024-04-01 09:01:44,672 UnixSocketClient.java:645 - Error reporting: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal initial capacity: -231741684
    at java.util.HashMap.\<init\>(HashMap.java:450) \~\[na:1.8.0_402\]
    at java.util.HashMap.\<init\>(HashMap.java:469) \~\[na:1.8.0_402\]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:111) \~\[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10\]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:94) \~\[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10\]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:102) \~\[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10\]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.getApproximateKeyCount(SSTableReader.java:254) \~\[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10\]
    at org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamilyMetrics$9.getValue(ColumnFamilyMetrics.java:293) \~\[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10\]
    at org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamilyMetrics$9.getValue(ColumnFamilyMetrics.java:287) \~\[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10\]
    at com.datastax.mcac.UnixSocketClient.writeMetric(UnixSocketClient.java:654) \[datastax-mcac-agent.jar:na\]
    at com.datastax.mcac.UnixSocketClient.access$700(UnixSocketClient.java:67) \[datastax-mcac-agent.jar:na\]
    at com.datastax.mcac.UnixSocketClient$2.lambda$onGaugeAdded$0(UnixSocketClient.java:521) \~\[datastax-mcac-agent.jar:na\]
    at com.datastax.mcac.UnixSocketClient.writeGroup(UnixSocketClient.java:634) \[datastax-mcac-agent.jar:na\]
    at com.datastax.mcac.UnixSocketClient.lambda$restartMetricReporting$1(UnixSocketClient.java:613) \[datastax-mcac-agent.jar:na\]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) \~\[na:1.8.0_402\]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:126) \~\[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final\]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399) \~\[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final\]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:307) \~\[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final\]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131) \~\[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final\]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) \~\[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final\]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) \~\[na:1.8.0_402\]


Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

From a quick browse of the stack trace, it looks like the exception is thrown when Cassandra is accessing one of the SSTables. It seems to fail when attempting to access the table of contents for a SSTable (*-TOC.txt).
My suspicion is that the TOC is corrupt so when MetadataSerializer.deserialize() tries to get the number of SSTable components, it fails leading to the negative HashMap size.
You'll need to review other entries in the logs for clues that might help determine the underlying issue. Cheers!

Thank you Eric. I do not see any other error or warning in the logs except this one
